# Assign the same value to multiple theme elements in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I feel like this is quite an easy question, but I couldn't find it asked anywhere. Nor could I find anything in the docs.

Is it possible in `ggplot2` to assign the same value to multiple `theme` elements? For instance, I can write my theme declaration as follows:

```
 theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "gray25"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        line = element_line(colour = "gray25"),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(colour = "gray25"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour = "gray25"),
        plot.title = element_text(colour = "gray25", face="bold",vjust=2))
```

But this seems highly repetetive. Isn't there something like a conjunction to assign the same value to multiple elements? Something like this for instance.

```
   theme(axis.text & legend.title & legend.text & plot.title = element_text(colour = "gray25"),
        labels bold 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(face="bold",vjust=2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`?theme`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html), you find that "Theme elements can inherit properties from other theme elements". For all individual theme elements, you find which element they inherit from. Thus, you can try to change as many properties as possible in the 'top level' in order to avoid redundancy. You can read more in the [official `theme` vignette](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html), where you also a find visualization of the inheritance between elements:
[image]

If you have a `theme` which you wish to use repeatedly (e.g. for specific journals or publishers), you may customize and save your own `themes`. For example, you may start from the [**default `theme`**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/ggplot2-0.9.2/R/theme-defaults.r), make your changes, save it, and use it just by adding `+ theme_bw_custom` (or whatever you name it) to the end of your plotting code.

See also  and [`ggthemes`](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes), which may serve as a starting point when creating your own `themes`.