# Is there an elegant way of having uniform font size for the whole plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I read online that the size of the fonts in a plot plotted with `ggplot2` is relative to the `base_size` specified in the `theme()`.

I also found that the size of the specific elements can be modified by doing something like:

```
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5) )
```

I am using the `theme_bw()` and would like all of the text in my plot: the labels of the axis, the title of the legend, the items in the legend, the breaks in the axis, to have the same font size. How can this be done?

**EDIT:**

I (almost) achieve what I want by using the `theme_tufte()` as suggester by @lawyeR.

```
g + theme_tufte() + theme(axis.rect=element_line() )
```

gives me a plot with x and y axis drawn as lines. However I would like to have the plot where x and y axis form a box.

How can I draw a box for the x and y axis?

Comment: I think [**this Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841591/assign-the-same-value-to-multiple-theme-elements-in-ggplot2/) is relevant.

Comment: Set the font size manually like `txt <- element_text(size = 16, colour = "black", face = "plain"); ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_histogram() + theme(text = txt, plot.title = txt, axis.title = txt, axis.text = txt) + ggtitle("mpg")`

Comment: Look at the ggthemes package.  I use theme_tufte from it which sticks with one font size and looks very clean

Comment: @lukeA is it possible to assign the same value to  theme(text, plot.title, axis.title, axis.text) by referring to the internal variable `base_size` of `theme_bw()`

Comment: @lawyeR how can I show the axis in `theme_tufte()`, because they don't appear when using this theme.

Comment: @cross: If you rewrite your own theme_bw function, why not (you get the code by just typing `theme_bw`).

Comment: `theme_tufte() + theme(axis.line=element_line())` will add lines, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22116880/4317408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem creating a theme of my own, which combines theme_bw() as its basic theme + the suggestion form @lukeA, + some custom stuff which I need.

```
theme_my <- function(base_size = 14, base_family = "Palatino")
{
  txt <- element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "plain")
  bold_txt <- element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold")

  theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) +
  theme(
    legend.key = element_blank(), 
    strip.background = element_blank(), 

    text = txt, 
    plot.title = txt, 

    axis.title = txt, 
    axis.text = txt, 

    legend.title = bold_txt, 
    legend.text = txt ) 
}
```